# Microsoft Word 2016 applying styles and text being placed in text box with anchor

Tags: microsoft-word

I have recently started a new business and have had a template Microsoft Word 2016 document prepared for me to use as headed note paper. There is an image in the header.

I have been modifying the Header styles (e.g. Header 1, Header 2 etc.) - which is all fine. However, when I apply a chosen style (e.g. Header 1) to the text, it seems to place a text box around the text - why?!

There is also a blue anchor next to the text box.

Can anyone please help me?

Many thanks

Comment: Looks like your heading text is inside a [text box](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Add-or-delete-a-text-box-6cbd2c67-2c40-4096-9dcb-9ad6ddbb2b25)

Comment: Thanks. The problem is that the text isn't in a text box before applying the style. I don't want it in a text box.

Comment: Then you need to edit the heading style I guess ...